# Use wait() on constant String's or global objects in java

Tags: java

why we do not call `wait()` on constant String's or global objects using multiple threads.

Anyone please give the suggestion to me

Comment: you'll need to be more specific..

Comment: You can, but it's a very bad idea. If you lock on a global object and you have a library which also locks on this object, you might have no idea how that will impact your program.

Answer (score 0):

@Atif
Well that reference above clearly explains the problem, may be I'll try to put it in different way.
See say you have a string str = "abc". Now because of flyweight patter JAVA would reuse the string. So if you declare another String str2 = "abc". Because of the way string pool is used both of these objects point to the same memory location/ object. 
Now say if you want to have lock on str, it would eventually lock str2 also.
Which can create problem.
Now there could be hundreds and thousands of such strings pointing to the same memory location, now Imagine how unpredictable result would be.

Let me know if you need further explanation.